# What is the <=> ("spaceship", three-way comparison) operator in C++?

Tags: c++, operators, c++20, spaceship-operator

While I was trying to learn about **C++** operators, I stumbled upon the following table that listed a strange comparison operator. What does this `<=>` operator do?

[image: 2017 image of a table from cppreference.com]
<sub>Since 2017 cppreference.com updated that page and now contains [detailed information](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison) about the`<=>`operator.</sub>

Answer (score 160, accepted):

On [2017-11-11](https://herbsutter.com/2017/11/11/trip-report-fall-iso-c-standards-meeting-albuquerque/), the ISO C++ committee  adopted  [Herb Sutter](https://herbsutter.com/about/)'s proposal for the **<=> "spaceship" three-way comparison operator** as one of the new features that were added to **C++20**. In the paper titled [Consistent comparison](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0515r2.pdf) Sutter, Maurer and Brown demonstrate the concepts of the new design. For an overview of the proposal, here's an excerpt from the article:

> The expression **a <=> b** returns an object that compares **<0** if **a <
> b**, compares **>0** if **a > b**, and compares **==0** if a and b are
> equal/equivalent.
>
> **Common case:** To write all comparisons for your type **X** with type **Y**, with memberwise semantics, just write:
>
> ```
> auto X::operator<=>(const Y&) =default;
> ```
>
> **Advanced cases:** To write all comparisons for your type **X** with type **Y**, just write **operator<=>** that takes a **Y**, can use
> **=default** to get memberwise semantics if desired, and returns the
> appropriate category type:
>
> - Return an **_ordering** if your type naturally supports **<**, and we’ll efficiently generate symmetric **<**, **>**, **<=**, **>=**, **==**, and
>   **!=**; otherwise return an **_equality**, and we’ll efficiently generate
>   symmetric **==** and **!=**.
> - Return **strong_** if for your type **a == b** implies **f(a) == f(b)** (substitutability, where **f** reads only comparison-salient state that
>   is accessible using the public **const** members), otherwise return
>   **weak_**.

| Comparison Categories |
| --- |

Five comparison categories are defined as `std::` types,
with the following predefined values:

```
┌──────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────┬─────────────┐
│                  │          Numeric  values          │ Non-numeric │
│     Category     ├──────┬────────────┬───────────────┤             │
│                  │ -1   │ 0          │ +1            │   values    │
├──────────────────┼──────┼────────────┼───────────────┼─────────────┤
│ strong_ordering  │ less │ equal      │ greater       │             │
│ weak_ordering    │ less │ equivalent │ greater       │             │
│ partial_ordering │ less │ equivalent │ greater       │ unordered   │
│ strong_equality  │      │ equal      │ nonequal      │             │
│ weak_equality    │      │ equivalent │ nonequivalent │             │
└──────────────────┴──────┴────────────┴───────────────┴─────────────┘
```

Implicit conversions between these types are defined as follows:

- `strong_ordering` with values {`less`, `equal`, `greater`} implicitly converts to:

  - `weak_ordering` with values {`less`, `equivalent`, `greater`}
  - `partial_ordering` with values {`less`, `equivalent`, `greater`}
  - `strong_equality` with values {`unequal`, `equal`, `unequal`}
  - `weak_equality` with values {`nonequivalent`, `equivalent`, `nonequivalent`}
- `weak_ordering` with values {`less`, `equivalent`, `greater`} implicitly converts to:

  - `partial_ordering` with values {`less`, `equivalent`, `greater`}
  - `weak_equality` with values {`nonequivalent`, `equivalent`, `nonequivalent`}
- `partial_ordering` with values {`less`, `equivalent`, `greater`, `unordered`} implicitly converts to:

  - `weak_equality` with values {`nonequivalent`, `equivalent`, `nonequivalent`, `nonequivalent`}
- `strong_equality` with values {`equal`, `unequal`} implicitly converts to:

  - `weak_equality` with values {`equivalent`, `nonequivalent`}

| Three-way comparison |
| --- |

The`<=>`token is introduced. The character sequence`<=>`tokenizes to`<= >`, in old source code. For example,`X<&Y::operator<=>`needs to add a space to retain its meaning.

The overloadable operator`<=>`is a three-way comparison function and has precedence higher than`<` and lower than`<<`. It returns a type that can be compared against literal`0`but other return types are allowed such as to support expression templates. All`<=>`operators defined in the language and in the standard library return one of the 5 aforementioned`std::`comparison category types.

For language types, the following built-in`<=>`same-type comparisons are provided. All are *constexpr*, except where noted otherwise. These comparisons cannot be invoked heterogeneously using scalar promotions/conversions.

- For`bool`, integral, and pointer types,`<=>`returns`strong_ordering`.
- For pointer types, the different cv-qualifications and derived-to-base conversions are allowed to invoke a homogeneous built-in`<=>`, and there are built-in heterogeneous`operator<=>(T*, nullptr_t)`. Only comparisons of pointers to the same object/allocation are constant expressions.
- For fundamental floating point types,`<=>` returns`partial_ordering`, and can be invoked heterogeneously by widening arguments to a larger floating point type.
- For enumerations,`<=>` returns the same as the enumeration's underlying type's`<=>`.
- For`nullptr_t`,`<=>` returns`strong_ordering`and always yields`equal`.
- For copyable arrays,`T[N] <=> T[N]`returns the same type as`T`'s`<=>`and performs lexicographical elementwise comparison. There is no`<=>`for other arrays.
- For`void`there is no`<=>`.

<sub>To better understand the inner workings of this operator, please read the original [paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0515r2.pdf). This is just what I've found out using search engines. Also, check out [Comparison Operators, including Three-Way Comparison(C++20)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading/77055231#77055231).</sub>

Comment: As if cpp wasn't complex enough already. Why not simply write a comparison method...

Comment: @Leandro The spaceship operator *is* that comparison method. Additionally, it Just Works and writes (or deletes) the six other comparison operators. I’ll take one comparison operator function written over six individual boilerplates.

Comment: Note that the `_equality` types died: it turned out that `<=>` plays well with the four relational operators but not as well with the two equality operators (although there’s some intense syntactic sugar to support the common case where you want all of them).

Answer (score 227):

This is called the **three-way comparison** operator.

According to the [P0515](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0515r0.pdf) paper proposal:

> There’s a new three-way comparison operator, `<=>`. The expression `a <=> b` returns an object that compares `<0` if `a < b`, compares `>0` if `a > b`, and compares `==0` if `a` and `b` are equal/equivalent.
>
> To write all comparisons for your type, just write `operator<=>` that
>   returns the appropriate category type:
>
> - Return **an _ordering** if your type naturally supports `<`, and we’ll efficiently generate `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, `==`,  and `!=`;
>     otherwise return **an _equality**, and we’ll efficiently generate
>     **==** and **!=**.
> - Return strong if for your type `a == b` implies `f(a) == f(b)` (substitutability, where f reads only  comparison-salient state
>     accessible using the nonprivate const interface), otherwise return
>     weak.

The [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison) says:

> The three-way comparison operator expressions have the form
>
> ```
> lhs <=> rhs   (1)
> ```
>
> The expression returns an object that
>
> - compares `<0` if `lhs < rhs`
> - compares `>0` if `lhs > rhs`
> - and compares `==0` if `lhs` and `rhs` are equal/equivalent.

Comment: For those who are confused (like I was) about what "compares `<0`", "compares `>0`", and "compares `==0`" means, they mean the `<=>` returns a negative, positive, or zero value, depending on the arguments. Much like `strncmp` and `memcmp`.

Comment: The first bullet-point says that if `<` is defined then the compiler will generate `==` - but how is that possible? `'a' < 'b' == 1`, but both `'a' < 'a'` and `'c' < 'a'` are both `== 0` so it shouldn't be possible to derive a comparison to be used by `==` without further information.

Comment: @Dai even though both `'a' < 'a'` and `'c' < 'a'` are both false, `'a' < 'a'` and `'a' < 'c'` are not. IN strong ordering following is true: `a != b` → `a < b || b < a`

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Ah, so it can be defined/generated as `operator==(T x, T y) { return !(x < y) && !(y < x); }` and `operator!=(T x, T y) { return (x < y) || (y < x); }` - ah-ha! Of course this is less efficient than a true `==` as it invokes the comparison twice, but still neat.

Comment: What do "return strong" and "return weak" mean?

Comment: What does `compares <0` mean? Can you give a use-case example?

Comment: @hkBattousai it means that the object returns, when compared `< 0` evaluates to true. That is, if `a < b` then `(a <=> b) < 0` is always true.

Comment: @hkBattousai I had the same question! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47498486/what-does-compares-0-mean

Comment: So `a <=> 0` is the sign function?

Comment: @lucidbrot it is not "return strong" or "return weak". It is "strong ordering" and "weak ordering". OT,  but the former means a "transitive none-reflective relation", while the later means "transitive reflective relation". Refer to "relation" in modern algebra.

Answer (score 29):

**Defaulting `<=>` automatically gives `==, !=, <, >, <=, >=` for free**

C++20 has a new "default comparison" feature setup so that defaulting `<=>` gives all the others for free. I believe that this has been the major motivation behind the addition of `operator<=>`.

Adapted from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons:

main.cpp

```
#include <cassert>
#include <compare>
#include <set>

struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
    auto operator<=>(const Point&) const = default;
};

int main() {
    Point pt1{1, 1}, pt2{1, 2};

    // Just to show it Is enough for `std::set`.
    std::set<Point> s;
    s.insert(pt1);

    // All of these are automatically defined for us!
    assert(!(pt1 == pt2));
    assert( (pt1 != pt2));
    assert( (pt1 <  pt2));
    assert( (pt1 <= pt2));
    assert(!(pt1 >  pt2));
    assert(!(pt1 >= pt2));
}
```

compile and run:

```
sudo apt install g++-10
g++-10 -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c++20 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o main.out main.cpp
./main.out
```

An equivalent more explicit version of the above would be:

```
struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
    auto operator<=>(const Point& other) const {
        if (auto cmp = x <=> other.x; cmp != 0)
            return cmp;
        return y <=> other.y;
    }
    bool operator==(const Point& other) const = default;
};
```

In this case, we need to explicitly set `bool operator==(const Point& other) const = default;` because if `operator<=>` is not defaulted (e.g. as given explicitly above), then `operator==` is not automatically defaulted:

> Per the rules for any `operator<=>` overload, a defaulted `<=>` overload will also allow the type to be compared with `<`, `<=`, `>`, and `>=`.
>
> If `operator<=>` is defaulted and `operator==` is not declared at all, then `operator==` is implicitly defaulted.

The above example uses the same algorithm as the default `operator<=>`, as explained by cppreference as:

> The default `operator<=>` performs lexicographical comparison by successively comparing the base (left-to-right depth-first) and then non-static member (in declaration order) subobjects of T to compute <=>, recursively expanding array members (in order of increasing subscript), and stopping early when a not-equal result is found

Before C++20, you could not do something like `operator== = default`, and defining one operator would not lead to the others being defined, e.g. the following fails to compile with `-std=c++17`:

```
#include <cassert>

struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
    auto operator==(const Point& other) const {
        return x == other.x && y == other.y;
    };
};

int main() {
    Point pt1{1, 1}, pt2{1, 2};

    // Do some checks.
    assert(!(pt1 == pt2));
    assert( (pt1 != pt2));
}
```

with error:

```
main.cpp:16:18: error: no match for ‘operator!=’ (operand types are ‘Point’ and ‘Point’)
   16 |     assert( (pt1 != pt2));
      |              ~~~ ^~ ~~~
      |              |      |
      |              Point  Point
```

The above does compile under `-std=c++20` however.

Related:

- [Are any C++ operator overloads provided automatically based on others?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32816843/are-any-c-operator-overloads-provided-automatically-based-on-others)
- [Why should I use the three-way comparison operator (<=>) instead of the two-way comparison operators? Does this have an advantage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67284403/why-should-i-use-the-three-way-comparison-operator-instead-of-the-two-way)

**The return type of `<=>`: `std::strong_ordering` vs `std::weak_ordering` vs `std::partial_ordering`**

The return type of `<=>` is not an `int` (-1, 0, 1), but rather an object of one of several types, which can then be compared to `int`, and which give further information about what kind of ordering is implemented notably:

- strong ordering: every element has a unique position https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order
- weak ordering: some elements may be in a draw: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering
- partial ordering: some elements may not even be comparable to other elements https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set

When we gave the implementation:

```
    auto operator<=>(const Point& other) const {
        if (auto cmp = x <=> other.x; cmp != 0)
            return cmp;
        return y <=> other.y;
    }
```

`auto` would have given us `std::strong_ordering` because that is what `<=>` returns between two integers as mentioned at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison

> Otherwise, if the operands have integral type, the operator yields a prvalue of type std::strong_ordering

and this is the semantic that we'd expect for integer points.

`partial_ordering` is what you get when doing `<=>` between floats due to the possibility of `NaN` which is "uncomparable".

TODO concrete examples of `weak_ordering` and `partial_ordering`.

[Practical meaning of std::strong_ordering and std::weak_ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51160471/practical-meaning-of-stdstrong-ordering-and-stdweak-ordering) suggests that there is currently no example of them making a different in the standard library.

Related: [PartialOrdering, StrictWeakOrdering, TotalOrdering, what's the main difference in application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781405/partialordering-strictweakordering-totalordering-whats-the-main-difference-i)

Tested on Ubuntu 20.04, GCC 10.2.0.

Comment: When not defaulting `<=>` should it give `==` as well? it happen to overload `>` and `<` for me, but yells `==` operator is missing... when defaulting there's not issue.

Comment: @TonyTannous that seems to be the expected behaviour according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons "Per the rules for any operator<=> overload, a defaulted <=> overload will also allow the type to be compared with <, <=, >, and >=. If operator<=> is defaulted and operator== is not declared at all, then operator== is implicitly defaulted." The solution is to add `bool operator==(const Point& other) const = default;` as in one of my examples.

Comment: Yes, I also found the [motivation](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1185r2.html#motivation) behind this in [p1185r2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1185r2.html)

Comment: `<=>` should be returning some comparison category (in your example, `std::strong_ordering` makes sense). If you make it return `int`, it becomes non-composable.

Comment: @JanSchultke thanks, I didn't know that., updated trying to fix it. What does non-composable mean? Can you link to an example where it can be seen?

Comment: If you change `T` to `int` in this example (https://godbolt.org/z/9fYoY3jKc), it fails to compile. You need to use the comparison categories for the compiler to be able to compose a defaulted `<=>` for containing types. `std::common_comparison_category` doesn't work with `int`.

Answer (score 23):

Three-Way Comparison operator (<=>) is introduced in C++ 20.

This expression returns the object as below;

```
auto cmp  = a <=> b;

cmp > 0 if a > b
cmp = 0 if a == b
cmp < 0 if a < b
```

Example Program

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        int lhs = 10, rhs = 20;
        auto result = lhs <=> rhs;

        if (result < 0) {
                cout << "lhs is less than rhs" << endl;
        }
        else if (result > 0) {
                cout << "lhs is greater than rhs" << endl;
        }
        else {
                cout << "lhs and rhs are equal" << endl;
        }

}
```

How to compile and run?

```
g++-10 threewaycmp.cpp -std=c++20
./a.out
```

Result

```
lhs is less than rhs
```

Please refer to below link for more details
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison

Answer (score 11):

**This answer has become irrelevant since the referenced web page has changed**

The [web page you are referencing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison) was broken. It was being edited a lot that day and different parts were not in sync.  The status when I was looking at it was:

At the top of the page it lists the currently existing comparison operators (in C++14).  There is no `<=>` there.

At the bottom of the page, they should have listed the same operators, but they goofed and added this future suggestion.

`gcc` doesn't know about `<=>` yet (and with `-std=c++14`, never will), so it thinks you meant `a <= > b`. This explains the error message.

If you try the same thing five years from now you will probably get a better error message, something like `<=> not part of C++14.`

Comment: The web page OP links to is correct, as is the separate page you link to. It qualifies the `<=>` operator with the (since C++20) label, telling you which version of the standard to expect it in. Standards labeling is a convention that cppreference.com follows. Of course you don't have a compiler that came back in a time machine to support it for you, but cpprefernce tells you (correctly) what to expect.

Comment: Yes, but... Not an answer. You are commenting... or something.

Comment: I intended to link to the same web page as the question, but missed.  I think I answered the parts of the question other answers didn't. I ignored the main bolded question since other had already answered that.

Comment: This answer doesn't attempt to answer the question *"What is the `<=>` operator?"* at all. It would have been better as a comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

The virtue of <=> is with complex types whose comparison is expensive, for situations like tree navigation.  You can "int x = A <=> B;" once and then determine >, <, >=, <=, ==, != from x without additional comparisons of A and B.  For a tree, imagine bool find(root, A){ if root is nullptr return false; int x = A <=> root->B; if !x, you found it return true, else if x < 0, find left, else find right}.  (Tune for tail recursion.)

I thought some language had a three way control flow for this, like switch, but it is hard to recall via google.  It's a situation going back to C strcmp(), memcmp(), continuing with JAVA compareTo().  Crowdsource me on this!