# Practical meaning of std::strong_ordering and std::weak_ordering

Tags: c++, c++20, spaceship-operator

I've been reading a bit about C++20's [consistent comparison](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0515r3.pdf) (i.e. `operator<=>`) but couldn't understand what's the practical difference between `std::strong_ordering` and `std::weak_ordering` (same goes for the `_equality` version for this manner).
Other than being very descriptive about the substitutability of the type, does it actually affect the generated code? Does it add any constraints for how one could use the type?
Would love to see a real-life example that demonstrates this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Does it add any constraints for how one could use the type?

<s>One very significant constraint (which wasn't intended by the original paper) was the adoption of the significance of `strong_ordering` by [P0732](https://wg21.link/p0732) as an indicator that a class type can be used as a non-type template parameter. `weak_ordering` isn't sufficient for this case due to how template equivalence has to work.</s> This is no longer the case, as non-type template parameters no longer work this way (see [P1907R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1907r0.html) for explanation of issues and [P1907R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1907r1.html) for wording of the new rules).

Generally, it's possible that some algorithms simply require `weak_ordering` but other algorithms require `strong_ordering`, so being able to annotate that on the type might mean a compile error (insufficiently strong ordering provided) instead of simply failing to meet the algorithm's requirements at runtime and hence just being undefined behavior. But all the algorithms in the standard library and the Ranges TS that I know of simply require `weak_ordering`. I do not know of one that requires `strong_ordering` off the top of my head.

> Does it actually affect the generated code?

Outside of the cases where `strong_ordering` is required, or an algorithm explicitly chooses different behavior based on the comparison category, no.

Answer (score 5):

There really isn't **any** reason to have `std::weak_ordering`.  It's true that the standard describes operations like sorting in terms of a ["strict" weak order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering), but there's an isomorphism between strict weak orderings and a *totally* ordered **partition** of the original set into incomparability equivalence classes.  It's rare to encounter generic code that is interested both in the **order** structure (which considers each equivalence class to be one "value") and in some possibly finer notion of **equivalence**: note that when the standard library uses `<` (or `<=>`) it does not use `==` (which might be finer).

The usual example for `std::weak_ordering` is a case-insensitive string, since for instance printing two strings that differ only by case certainly produces different **behavior** despite their equivalence (under any operator).  However, lots of types can have different behavior despite being `==`: two `std::vector<int>` objects, for instance, might have the same contents and different capacities, so that appending to them might invalidate iterators differently.

The simple fact is that the "equality" implied by `std::strong_ordering::equivalent` but not by `std::weak_ordering::equivalent` is *irrelevant* to the very code that stands to benefit from it, because **generic** code doesn't depend on the implied behavioral changes, and non-generic code doesn't need to distinguish between the ordering types because it knows the rules for the type on which it operates.

The standard attempts to give the distinction meaning by talking about "substitutability", but that is inevitably **circular** because it can sensibly refer only to the very state examined by the comparisons.  This [was discussed](https://github.com/cplusplus/nbballot/issues/169) prior to publishing C++20, but (perhaps for the obvious reasons) not much of the planned further discussion has taken place.