# How to force std::weak_ordering

Tags: c++, c++20, spaceship-operator, strict-weak-ordering

While trying out the new <del>Tie-Interceptor</del> three-way comparison operator `<=>` I was wondering what would be an example such that

```
struct Foo {
    /*
       ....
    */
    auto operator<=>(const Foo &rhs) const = default;
};
```

would lead to a compiler error with

```
Foo Bar1;
Foo Bar2;
std::strong_ordering(Bar1 <=> Bar2);
```

but not with

```
Foo Bar1;
Foo Bar2;
std::weak_ordering(Bar1 <=> Bar2);
```

What would be an example for `Foo`? In other words how would `Foo` not imply substitutability?
I know that I could write my own implementation of the operator which returns `std::weak_ordering ... less/greater/equivalent` but how to force the compiler to do so?

I've read [Practical meaning of strong_ordering and weak_ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51160471/practical-meaning-of-strong-ordering-and-weak-ordering) among others so far.

Comment: please always use the language tag

Comment: Do note: The three comparison category types ([cmp.categories]) (the types std​::​strong_­ordering, std​::​weak_­ordering, and std​::​partial_­ordering) are not predefined; if the header <compare> ([compare.syn]) is not imported or included prior to a use of such a class type – even an implicit use in which the type is not named (e.g., via the auto specifier in a defaulted three-way comparison or use of the built-in operator) – the program is ill-formed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ... but how to force the compiler to do so?

When you use `auto` as the return type of defaulted `operator<=>`, the compiler will pick the common comparison category of all the members. So if you have something like:

```
// any type that is weakly ordered
struct Weak {
    bool operator==(Weak const&) const;
    std::weak_ordering operator<=>(Weak const&) const;
};

struct Foo {
    Weak w;
    int i;
    auto operator<=>(Foo const&) const = default;
};
```

Then using `<=>` on two instances of type `Foo` will give you a `weak_ordering`, since that's the common comparison category of `Weak` and `int`.

In the same way that given:

```
struct Bar {
    float f;
    auto operator<=>(Bar const&) const = default;
};
```

`Bar::operator<=>` gives you a `std::partial_ordering`.

There are no core language types that give you a `std::weak_ordering`, but there *are* some library types that might:

```
// some typical C++17 comparable type
struct Widget {
    bool operator==(Widget const&) const;
    bool operator<(Widget const&) const;
};

struct LotsOfWidgets {
    std::vector<Widget> widgets;
    auto operator<=>(LotsOfWidgets const&) const = default;
};
```

The `<=>` here returns `std::weak_ordering` (to avoid having to assume what it is you meant by `<` and `==`).

---

Or you could simply provide that yourself. You don't *have* to use `auto`:

```
struct WeakInt {
    int i;
    friend std::weak_ordering operator<=>(WeakInt, WeakInt) = default;
};
```

Comment: Very detailed, thank you! Very good point with `LotsOfWidgets `!

Answer (score 2):

`weak_ordering` is a user's choice, an explicit expression of the meaning of comparison for the type. No fundamental types are weakly ordered (floats use `partial_ordering`), and most standard library types that are ordered in some way either mirror the ordering of some template parameter or pick a more specific ordering.

So `weak_ordering` happens by `= default` only if a subobject of `Foo` itself uses `weak_ordering`.