# why C++ std::min_element library function accepts functor that takes function object of bool return type rather than int like in C?

Tags: c++, stl

The C++ standard library function `std::min_element()` accepts a function object as is last argument, and that object's return type is `bool`. Why is it not `int`?

With true or false, we have only two options: `<` or `>`, but what if two entries are the same i.e. `==`?

In C, this situation is handled by choosing the return type as `int`. But this is not done for `std::min_element()` in C++.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: which compiler???

Comment: @santoshdhanawade it's in the standard, so all of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll point out that this is consistent with other parts of `std`, such as `sort` and `map`, which all order things based on a functor which satisfies [Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare). The same question can be extended to all these things.

> What is the reason?

The original author, and the standards committee, thought that it was a more natural way of expressing ordering.

There are some problems with using three way compare via `int`.

- `int` has more than three values. You therefore have to do further arithmetic on the return value.
- It's easier to fall into undefined behaviour

```
struct three_way_compare
{
     int operator()(int lhs, int rhs) { return lhs - rhs; }
     // Undefined behaviour when rhs is a large positive value and lhs is a large negative value
}
```

You can synthesize three way comparison by calling your functor twice. The reference defines the requirements using

> `equiv(a, b)`, an expression equivalent to `!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)`

Note that for C++20, three way comparison is being added to the language with [`operator <=>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47466358/what-is-the-operator-in-c). I'm not sure if existing algorithms are being changed to utilise it, when available.

Comment: Unless you have `NAN` floating point values in your container, in which case **all** comparisons return `false`.

Comment: @KhouriGiordano Yes, it's undefined to try to sort NAN.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it is detail. I think I am more interested in knowing how the algorithm implementation determines whether two entries are of equal values based on true/false output from the compare function. Suppose I decide to write implementation of compare function as follows:

bool compare(int & val1, int & val2)
{
    return (val1 < val2)
}

With such compare function, can the algorithm know whether two entries are having same value by using !comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a) ? It evaluates to false with above compare function.

Comment: @Rushikesh `comp` is whatever comparison you provide. For the case of `<`, it treats as equivalent any `a` and `b` such that `!(a < b) && !(b < a)` is true. That need not the same as `a == b`

Answer (score 7):

What would you gain from that information? The function is supposed to return the smallest element (hence the name `min_element`). It doesn't need to care about equality, what would you gain from it in the end result? A boolean value is sufficient to tell whether one element is smaller than another. How you handle equality is up to your implementation of that callable.

In the words of [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element):

```
bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);
```

> comparison function object (i.e. an object that satisfies the requirements of Compare) which returns ​true if a is less than b.