# How to implement a map with three keys in C++ STL?

Tags: c++, oop, stl, c++17

So, I have a class

```
class table()
{
  public:
  string product, region, province ,price;
};
```

so i have an array of objects of the above shown class and my objective is to write a function with input as product, region, province the function searches this in the array and returns the price.

Now to search efficiently with least time I thought of using stl map in c++ but i require to have 3 keys in my map with price as the value,so I used this.

```
struct key
{
string product, region, province;
};
```

and my map definition is this.

```
unordered_map<key,string> mp;
```

1. Is this even practical to have three keys in map?
2. does having 3 keys affect the search time complexity for the map?

I am still pretty new to computer science field so please forgive me for any mistake in this question,
and also if i am completely wrong with the map idea a slight push in the right direction for me will be very helpful.
thankyou for your time.

Comment: All `std::unordered_map` cares about is (1) getting a hash value for the prospective key, and (2) in the event of collision (likely), the ability to perform equality comparison on to colliding keys. The guts of a key make no difference in either of the above intentions; that's up to you. You need to provide a hasher that consumes your key data for (1). You need to provide equivalence determination for (2). Doing both of those, I see no reason this wouldn't work, though I'm not entirely convinced it is *really* what you need. And no, it won't affect search big-O complexity.

Comment: `unordered_map` -- This is a hash map, thus you need to write a (good) hash function for those three strings.  You need to research hash tables, hash functions, etc., which are independent of C++ and STL.

Comment: So, the idea would be to loose the stl map and create a hashtable from scratch, with a good enough hash function to avoid collision?

Comment: Not what we said. If you want to use a `std::unordered_map` you certainly can. You should just have a better understanding of how they work in-general, and what is expected of the client code (yours) to make it work well. If you have a good hash function, you can use that in a `std::unordered_map` just as well as you can anywhere else, and as a freebie you don't have to reinvent the hash-table wheel.

Comment: @ApurvaHarsh -- The inner workings of the table is what `std::unordered_map` has to offer.  What *you* have to provide is the hash function to `std::unordered_map` so that it operates efficiently.  It is the writing of the hash function, when given three strings, that is the issue.  You would have needed that hash function anyway, regardless if you used `std::unordered_map` or came up with your own hash table.  Writing efficient hash functions when given `n` strings as the key is something that has been well-researched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do this with `std::unordered_map`, and it isn't as difficult as it may first seem. All a `std::unordered_map` cares about is:

1. The key type must be hashable using either a default hash algorithm or one provided to the container as a template-parameter type or a construction instance.
2. The key type must support equivalence checks (i.e. comparing two key instances for equivalence using either a custom "equals" type similar to the hasher template parameter argument, or the default `std::equals`, which uses `operator ==` with two instances).

This is easier to see than to explain. Below is a trivial example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <tuple>
#include <unordered_map>

struct MyKey
{
    struct Hash
    {
        // jacked up derivation of bernstiens string hasher
        std::size_t operator()(MyKey const& key) const
        {
            std::size_t hash = 5381u;
            for (auto c : key.s1)
                hash = (hash << 5) + hash + c;
            for (auto c : key.s2)
                hash = (hash << 5) + hash + c;
            for (auto c : key.s3)
                hash = (hash << 5) + hash + c;
            return hash;
        }
    };

    std::string s1, s2, s3;

    // equivalence determination.
    bool operator ==(MyKey const& key) const
    {
        return std::tie(s1, s2, s3) == std::tie(key.s1, key.s2, key.s3);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<MyKey, int, MyKey::Hash> ht;
    ht.insert(std::make_pair<MyKey>({ "one", "two", "three" }, 42));
    ht.insert(std::make_pair<MyKey>({ "four", "five", "six" }, 1999));
    ht.insert(std::make_pair<MyKey>({ "seven", "eight", "nine" }, 1999));

    auto it = ht.find(MyKey{ "one", "two", "three" });
    if (it != ht.end())
        std::cout << it->second << '\n';

    it = ht.find(MyKey{ "four", "five", "six" });
    if (it != ht.end())
        std::cout << it->second << '\n';

    it = ht.find(MyKey{ "seven", "eight", "nine" });
    if (it != ht.end())
        std::cout << it->second << '\n';

    // shoudl NOT find anything
    it = ht.find(MyKey{ "one", "three", "two" });
    if (it != ht.end())
        std::cout << it->second << '\n';
}
```

To answer probably the most important part of your question, no this does NOT affect search time. Obviously it takes longer to generate a hash value from three string than from one, but once that value is acquired the search mechanics are identical to any other unordered_map. If a collision is found, the equivalence check kicks in, and again, that's unavoidable, but not going affect the big-O complexity of your overall performance profile.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using map then you can use `tuple<type1, type2....>`

```cpp
map<tuple<int, int , int> , string> foo;

foo.insert(make_tuple(1,2,3), "bar");
foo[make_tuple(1,3,1)] = "bar1";
foo[{2,2,3}] = "bar2";
```

[c++ tuple](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)

Comment: For this solution don't we need to provide a comparison operator, can you show me how to do that?

Comment: tuple by default has overloaded  `<` same as `pair` so no need. it does all the operation in logarithmic time.

Comment: @ApurvaHarsh -- Note that a `std::map` is not a hash table, but is usually implemented as a balanced binary tree.  So just be aware that `std::map` maybe not what you really want, given your original question.  Look at WhozCraig's answer for an explanation.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie absolutely

Answer (score 1):

`std::map` is a touch easier to get working

```
struct key {
  std::string product, region, province;
  auto as_tie() const{
    return std::tie(product, region, province);
  }
  friend bool operator<( key const& lhs, key const& rhs ){
    return lhs.as_tie()<rhs.as_tie();
  }
};
```

now `key` works as a key in a `std::map`.  Here I let std tuple (via std tie) implement my `<` operator.

For an unordered map, you need to specialize std hash and provide `==` (or pass a hasher/equality function object to the template).

In C++20 you can just

```
auto operator<=>(key const&)const =default;
```

instead of the tie stuff and get map to work.

3 part keys don't change the big-O complexity of maps, ordered or not.

Unordered map still needs a custom hash.

Comment: can you explain this line of code       `auto operator<=>(key const&)const =default;`

Comment: @ApurvaHarsh https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47466358/what-is-the-operator-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you'll want to be able to hash multiple key fields to provide one high quality hash value, and - in the style of boost `hash_combine` - you can do that with:

```
template <class T>
inline void hash_combine(std::size_t& seed, T const& v) {
    seed ^= std::hash<T>()(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
}
```

...combined with a general-purpose `tuple` hash function...

```
struct hash_tuple {
    auto operator()(const auto& tuple) const {
        std::size_t seed = 0;
        std::apply([&](const auto& ...element){(..., hash_combine(seed, element));}, tuple);
        return seed;
    }
};
```

The above will work for any length of tuple, and any contained types that are themselves hashable.

You can then either use an `unordered_map` from a `std::tuple` of your key fields to the price `double`, as in:

```
using key = std::tuple<std::string, std::string, std::string>;
std::unordered_map<key, double, hash_tuple> m;
// ...then just use the map...
m[{"abc", "def", "ghi"}] = 3.14;
```

...or, you might want to have a `struct` with your keys and price combined...

```
struct X {
    std::string a, b, c;
    double price_;
    auto tie_keys() const { return std::tie(a, b, c); }
    bool operator==(const X& rhs) const {
        return tie_keys() == rhs.tie_keys();
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const X& x) {
        return os << x.a << ' ' << x.b << ' ' << x.c << ' ' << x.price_;
    }
};
```

...and store those in an `unordered_set<>`...

```
auto hash_fn = [](const X& x) { return hash_tuple{}(x.tie_keys()); };
std::unordered_set<X, decltype(hash_fn)> m2;
// ...and use it...
m2.emplace("ab", "cde", "fg", 3.14);
m2.emplace("hij", "kl", "mn", 2.71);
for (const auto& x : m2)
    std::cout << x << '\n';
```

You'll need various headers of course...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
```

> does having 3 keys affect the search time complexity for the map?

Not if you have a decent hash function.