# How to use spaceship <=> operator with strcmp style function?

Tags: c++, c++20, spaceship-operator

Suppose I have a C library with a struct `cat`, and a function `compare(cat a, cat b)` which returns an integer according for following rules :-

- if a < b then returns -1
- if a = b then returns  0
- if a > b then returns +1

I am writing c++ wrapper (say `catxx`, with `ct` as C struct member) for this library and would like to use the new C++20 spaceship operator.

```cpp
bool operator == (catxx& a, catxx& b)
{
    return !compare(a.ct, b.ct);
}

auto operator <=> (catxx& a, catxx& b)
{
    int result = compare(a.ct, b.ct);
    return /*what ?*/;
}
```

How would I do this ? I am unable to understand the ordering concept.

1. What if I had to use custom `if else` instead of `compare()` ?
2. What exactly is return type of operator<=> ?
3. What do weak_ordering, partial ordering etc. mean ?

Comment: What portion(s) of [the FAQ on the spaceship operator and its usage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47466358)  are unclear to you? If you can clarify your question, we can provide better help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison):

> The three-way comparison operator expressions have the form
>
> ```
> lhs <=> rhs
> ```
>
> The expression returns an object such that
>
> - `(a <=> b) < 0` if `lhs` < `rhs`
> - `(a <=> b) > 0` if `lhs` > `rhs`
> - `(a <=> b) == 0` if `lhs` and `rhs` are equal/equivalent.

So you can just simply do

```
auto operator <=> (catxx& a, catxx& b)
{
  return compare(a.ct, b.ct) <=> 0;
}
```

Since the operands are integral type, the operator yields a prvalue of type [`std::strong_ordering`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/compare/strong_ordering).

Comment: This will not implement `operator==`.

Comment: Isn't OP already implemented `operator==`?

Comment: And what exactly is return type of this operator ? what if i had to use some custom logic instead of compare() ?

Comment: For 2 integers `<=>` evaluates to a `std::strong_ordering`. You can use `std::strong_ordering::less`, `std::strong_ordering::equal` or `std::strong_ordering::greater` directly in your code like `if (a < b) return std::strong_ordering::less;`.